# Finding similar fragment in recorded speech

Tags: mfcc

I use MFCC algorithm for calculation of Mel-frequency coefficient for 2 files and DTW algorithm with Euclidean distance for finding similarity. I have results values around 400-600 on the files with the same word (cut from recorded speech of the same person). Is it right? Or I have a mistake in my implementation? I didn't find an implementation of MFCC in C#, so I edited some files from comirva (java), can it be the problem?
I have also tried Chi-Square distance, but it gives a negative results.

Comment: The statement "results values around 400-600" is completely meaningless without knowing more detail about the implementation.